# FB api returns score of test user but not only returns user score for real user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have both permissions approved publish_actions, user_friends still i dont see any friends score. When i do the same for test user it works. the api call is it retrieves only users score

**FB.API ("/app/scores?fields=score,user.limit(20)", HttpMethod.GET, ScoreCallback);**

neither does this

**FB.API ("/me/friends", HttpMethod.GET, Mycallback);**

Any help or suggestions is appricated

Comment: Did you _ask_ the users for those permissions, and did they actually _grant_ them? (Debug their access token, or call `/me/permissions` to find out.)

Comment: "data":[{"permission":"publish_actions","status":"granted"},{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"}]}. this is what i get and on fb its mentioned that user_friends is approved by default.

Comment: Approved means your app _can_ ask users for the permission - but you still have to _ask_ them.